# Any suggestions on the latest trend in version control for SQL Server 2014 and above?

Tags: version-control, sql-server-2014

For example when a developer makes changes in any of the database elements in a business critical database it should force them to commit the code before applying the changes to database itself. I came across Redgate sql source control which matches my expectation somehow. Still do we have any more tools or effective database practices that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Source Control or a tool like it (eg, ReadyRoll or VS Database Projects) I'd recommend also using [DLM Dashboard](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dlm/dlm-dashboard/).

The reason for this is that no tool can enforce changes to go through a process *if* people are given (too many) rights and are able to apply changes to production. It's then up to these people to correctly follow the process.

Although DLM Dashboard doesn't enforce changes to your database, it will alert you on changes made to production, warning you when out-of-process changes (aka "drift").

DLM Dashboard is free, which is another reason to use it!